# Debian - Nodejs is installed but npm isn't

Tags: node.js, npm, debian-stretch

I am following `https://github.com/nodesource/distributions` to install Nodejs v11.x on Debian. After following the two instructions, Nodejs seems to be installed fine and `nodejs -v` returns `v4.8.2`.

But npm doesn't seem to have been installed. `whereis npm` returns nothing and I am fairly certain there is no npm installed on my disk.

I have pasted the console log after the command `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_11.x | bash -` below:

```
+ apt-get update
Hit:1 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian stretch InRelease
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freecad-maintainers/freecad-stable/ubuntu cosmic InRelease [15.4 kB]
Hit:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease                                
Ign:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freecad-maintainers/freecad-stable/ubuntu cosmic InRelease           
Hit:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports InRelease                                                                         
Ign:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease                     
Ign:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco InRelease   
Hit:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco Release         
Hit:10 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco/main i386 Packages
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco/main amd64 Packages
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco/main all Packages
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco/main Translation-en_US
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco/main Translation-en
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco/main i386 Packages
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco/main amd64 Packages
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco/main all Packages
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco/main Translation-en_US
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco/main Translation-en
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco/main i386 Packages
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco/main amd64 Packages
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco/main all Packages
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco/main Translation-en_US
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco/main Translation-en
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco/main i386 Packages
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco/main amd64 Packages
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco/main all Packages
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco/main Translation-en_US
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco/main Translation-en
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco/main i386 Packages
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco/main amd64 Packages
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco/main all Packages
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco/main Translation-en_US
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco/main Translation-en
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Err:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco/main amd64 Packages
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco/main all Packages
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco/main Translation-en_US
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco/main Translation-en
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Fetched 15.4 kB in 16s (929 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/freecad-maintainers/freecad-stable/ubuntu cosmic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 005EAE8119BB5BCA
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/freecad-maintainers/freecad-stable/ubuntu cosmic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/dists/disco/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Error executing command, exiting
```

My guess is that the installer script stops midway during the process as apt-get is throwing an error. However even if that were the case, I have no idea how to tackle this problem. I don't want to remove the repositories for freecad and java to get apt to quit positively.

*If the answer is related to apt-get and is off-topic on this forum, maybe it can be migrated to askubuntu?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to fix the repository issues gives weird python errors, it might have to do with me having both python 2.7 and 3 installed in my system but I don't know for sure.

What I ended up doing is just removing the problematic repositories from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` temporarily and then running the curl script again. This makes the script run without any errors and afterwards, the command `apt install -y nodejs` installs the correct version along with npm.

The problem, it seems, was that debian's default repository also has a `nodejs` pacakge without npm. And due to the `apt-get update` error, the install script quit prematurely. Fixing that error did the job.

Answer (score 2):

well, first let's address the error you see regarding the repositories.

This line tells you the problem.

```
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/freecad-maintainers/freecad-stable/ubuntu cosmic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 005EAE8119BB5BCA
```

Did you follow the key installation instructions on the freecad page? See https://launchpad.net/~freecad-maintainers/+archive/ubuntu/freecad-stable

and click on Signing key - What's this?

As for the Node issue, try updating Node:
https://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/update-node-js-latest-version/

Also, try sudo apt-get install npm